# HP compaq nx5000 laptop freezes with 12.04, which kernel parameter could fix it?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I recovered an old laptop (HP compaq nx5000). It worked with Ubuntu Server 8.04 very good a lot years ago. I'm trying install Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 & 10.04, but the laptop freezes on the first 15 minutes.

I reinstalled Windows XP and the laptop works perfect, without freezes. I think is a kernel issue. I read this great [documentation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options), but I'm little lost with it. Which parameter could be the issue?

Comment: "Freezes" is too vague a problem to give you a definitive answer...more details, please?

Comment: @izx: Mouse, Caps lock, keyboard... all is freezed :P I instaled a lot of computers with Ubuntu, I think is some kernel issue :(

Comment: How much RAM have you got? The memory needed by Ubuntu has crept up over time... The HP Compaq nx5000 has, I believe, Intel video. Look at http://www.insidesocal.com/click/2010/02/intel-82830-cgc-830m-graphics.html

Comment: @arochester: The laptop has 256MB, I changed for 1 module of 1GB. With each module, same result. I discarded a RAM issue :) Thanks!

Comment: If the laptop only has 256Mb (1) Try to increase the amount of RAM if you can: or (2) Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu. They are far less demanding of memory. Are you using the Desktop disk (LiveCD) or the Alternate disk? The Desktop disk uses more memory than you have, to install. The Alternate disk is a straight install and is a better choice for you.

Comment: @arochester I tried 256Mb & 1Gb. Yes, I installed lubuntu 12.04 too. All the same result :(

Comment: Fixed! Just adding acpi=off to the kernel :) Thank you very much to all of you!!!

Comment: added an answer so other people can use this solution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look in `/etc/default/grub`

change the line

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`

and now just update grub with `sudo update-grub`.

[Source.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1323023)

Comment: Just one note: In this laptop you must install lubuntu 12.04, not ubuntu desktop 12.04.