# Ubuntu 12.04 blank purple splash screen after live install

Tags: installation, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old laptop freezes with 12.04, which kernel parameter could fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138245/old-laptop-freezes-with-12-04-which-kernel-parameter-could-fix-it)

I initially had problems running the live CD after downloading it and burning the iso to a CD.  After rebooting, the system would just hang with a blinking cursor at the black screen.  After pressing a key and getting to the advanced boot options, i selected no apci and selected try Ubuntu.  This seemed to work.

After loading from the live CD, I then selected the option to install the LTS.  The install seemed to finish successfully.  Upon reboot however, It hangs at the purple screen which is just blank.  I overwrote the previous OS which was Win7.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have? (AMD or nVIDIA?)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not at all able to boot into desktop than use `recovery mode` from the boot menu when you start up and see terminal prompt is available.

It may happen that GRUB failed to get correct resolution supported by your GPU, and a resolution too high or too low may result into unbootable system.

You can perform following steps to get bootsplash at correct/acceptable resolution on startup.

- Open terminal (if you're able to boot into desktop) as you'd need to run some commands to fix the problem. Or, you can perform following steps from `recovery mode` too.
- Identify your maximum supported screen resolution (assume 1024x768 as default/safer).
- Open `/etc/default/grub` in text editor as root, run in terminal.

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  - Alternatively, you can edit the file from within terminal using `nano` by running the same command with little modification as: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.
  - Just use Ctrl+O to save changes you make to the file and Ctrl+X to exit the editor.
- As the file opens in text editor, look for option `GRUB_GFXMODE` (it might be commented using '#', if so, remove preceeding '#' symbol to uncomment).
- Set option's value as following (you can use your screen's resolution in similar way).

  ```
  GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
  ```
- Save file and exit.
- Run following command to set boot splash to use framebuffer for showing bootsplash while booting up (correct me if I'm wrong).

  ```
  echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
  ```
- Now run following two commands **one-by-one**.

  ```
  sudo update-grub2

  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```
- Now reboot to see if you have bootsplash instead of blank purple screen.

This method has worked for most graphics cards, I don't know if its a fix or workaround, but ever since Ubuntu changed the bootsplash to the current one (Since 10.04) I always need to perform above steps after installing new version of Ubuntu to get bootsplash working on my laptop which has Intel integrated graphics.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include instructions to perform steps from recovery mode.